# Reading ARM CPU registers from LKM

Tags: hyperlink, arm, cpu-registers

I want to read the values stored in the Link Register or Frame Pointer from a linux kernel module and I am not sure the syntax to use.  For context, I've compiled Android goldfish 3.4 kernel and am using insmod to load my module into the kernel.

Comment: *Why* do you want this? Neither the link-register nor the frame-pointer are guaranteed to be used for their stated purpose.

Comment: Writing some inline assembly to extract a specific register is pretty trivial, but also fairly meaningless, because at best you'll only find out where _that piece of code_ was directly called from (which you almost certainly know) and where its own local stack frame is (whoop de do). It would be far more useful to start by explaining what you hope to achieve by this...

Comment: @EOF No but it's a great place to start for unwinding a stack from a ring-0 debugger!

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin Ring 0? Wrong architecture. I hope you realise that ARM has up to 7 banked link registers and at least two different frame pointer conventions (if at all) for whatever might be currently running, and that's not even considering the possibility that the question might actually be about inspecting the saved `pt_regs` of the userspace task calling into the module; in short, this question is unanswerable without considerably more detail, and currently far, far short of being a "useful programming question" for the site...

Comment: I did not know that. I use the term ring0 ubiquitously for "kernel mode".

Comment: @Notlikethat-- My motivation is academic.  I'm taking an operating system course and I'm trying to apply embedded operating system concepts.  I want to see how execution flows from user process through a system call and then return back to the user process.  I understand there are different stacks (kernel and user) and I'm trying to access the saved userspace return address (of my user process) on the kernel stack from inside my kernel module.  The solution I thought of was to access the LR register.

Comment: @AlfredP OK, well that should have been made clear in the question in the first place; please consider an [edit]. As per the earlier comments, the actual contents of r14 (LR) at any given time will be at best the immediate caller of the _current_ function; any child function call will trash that, and in any function complex enough to necessitate a stack frame r14 usually becomes one of the compiler's first choices for a scratch register. In short; the wrong tree to bark up.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of this area is entirely hobbyist in nature, someone else might know something really stylish that obviates this dangerous and hackish method.

As a philosophical issue, the kernel doesn't tamper with user-mode operation as part of it's normal duties. This means you are going to have to tamper with the direct operation of the kernel and potentially cause crashes, corruption and other problematic c-words.

There are two ways to go about doing this. You can go through the syscall entry/exit mechanism: switching a single running thread from running usermode code to running kernel code in the context of that thread while slyly replacing it's stored registers before it goes back again. The second is the context switch mechanism itself, which switches in kernel mode from running in the context of one thread to another, again replacing relevant stored register material.

The operating theory behind all of this is that each user thread has both a user-mode stack and a kernel-mode stack.  When a thread enters the kernel, the current value of the user-mode stack and instruction pointer are saved to the thread's *kernel*-mode stack, and the CPU switches to the kernel-mode stack.  The remaining register values and flags are then also saved to the kernel stack.

At this stage, you can directly read and modify those values prior to the process being returned off the run queue. After this, when your thread returns from the kernel to user-mode, the register values and flags are popped from the kernel-mode stack, then the user-mode stack and instruction pointer values are restored from the modified values on the kernel-mode stack.

The schedule has an internal mechanism that selects the process to run next, calling `switch_to()`. As the name implies, this function essentially just switches the kernel stacks - it saves the current value of the stack pointer into the TCB for the current thread (called `struct task_struct` in Linux), and loads a previously-saved stack pointer from the TCB for the next thread. You can use this to calculate the user-mode process in question (possibly requiring a cross-reference of existing kernel-mode process structures)

Answer (score 0):

The way to look at the state of the current userspace process from kernel-side is [`current_pt_regs()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=current_pt_regs) (cf. `task_pt_regs()` for a specific task). This gets you a pointer to a [`struct pt_regs`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/ptrace.h#L124), which is the same thing you'd find in the `mcontext_t` in a signal handler (on ARM at least). The kernel even provides nice accessor macros to make the whole caboodle rather civilised - reading through existing uses in the source should give a good feel of how to do it, but for the sake of completeness here's a trivial example<sup>*</sup>:

```
#include <asm/ptrace.h>

void func()
{
    struct pt_regs *regs = current_pt_regs();

    pr_info("User LR was %p\n", (void *)regs->ARM_lr);
}
```

You'd have to know the ABI details of the userspace binary to know which, if any, register is being used as a frame pointer, but if there is one it's typically in r11 or r7.

<sub><sub>*Code typed directly into browser late at night, usual disclaimers apply, etc.</sub></sub>

Comment: thanks...but there isn't a kernel macro to access the registers from android goldfish:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/android-goldfish-3.4/arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h